# Is a separate agent required for every monitored resource in GCP Stackdriver?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

Is a  separate  agent required for every monitored resource in GCP? For example if I am interested in metrics for  cpu,disk,memory , jvm etc , do I install a single agent or multiple agents  in my GCE instance to take care of the additional metrics that are offered by the monitoring agent when using Stackdriver ?

Answer (score 1):

You only need a single monitoring agent process per GCE instance to collect all of the [supported third-party metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/). Note that the instance *is* the monitored resource -- all of the metrics the agent collects are associated with the appropriate [gce_instance monitored resource](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources#tag_gce_instance).